# Error: /Stage[main]/Mcafeeepoagent/Service[cma]:

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

Error: /Stage[main]/Mcafeeepoagent/Service[cma]: Provider init is not functional on this host: I am using module Mcafeeepoagent puppet PE, on Linux REdHat

```
my code:
    1 class profile::mcafee_epo_agent (
      2 ){
      3
      4  if $::kernel == 'Linux'{
      5    class { 'mcafee_epo_agent':
      6      class_enabled          => true,
      7      agent_install_type     => 'script',
      8      agent_install_options  => '-i',
     9      agent_service_name     => 'cma',
     10      agent_service_ensure   => 'running',
     11      agent_service_enable   => true,
     12      agent_service_provider => 'init',
     13      agent_service_script   => '/etc/init.d/cma',
     14    }
     15  }
     16 }
```

Comment: And the version of RedHat is 7?

Comment: it is doing the same on linux 5 or 6 (2.6.32-343.el6.x86_64), The work around is to change init to "redhat" but I might need to have case statement for Centos.